# How do I slant vertical bar in the header?

Tags: fancyhdr, sv-classes

I understand that there is a solution for this, but I do not want to change the encoding of my file, i.e. utf8 to T1. I want to get the following headers, but it just isn't working. 
[image]

[image]

A friend suggested I use the following renewcommand with `\slshape`, but I wasn't too sure how to incorporate that into my `fancyhdr` coding.

```
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\chaptername\ \thechapter\ \textbar\ #1}{}}
```

How should I fix my problem to get the above header styles. My current coding is as follows:

```
\documentclass[envcountchap,sectrefs,12pt]{svmono} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[paperwidth=8.5in,paperheight=11in,includeall,
                  twoside,inner=1in,outer=0.5in,top=1cm,bottom=0.7cm,
                  marginparwidth=1.75in,headsep=0.25in,heightrounded]{geometry}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
%\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\chaptername\ \thechapter\ \textbar\ #1}{}}
\fancyhead[RE]{\ifnum\value{chapter}=0 \runheadsize\runheadstyle\slshape\leftmark \fi
            %The chapter number only if = 0
            \ifnum\value{chapter}>0 \slshape Experiment\ \thechapter\ |\ \leftmark \fi %This LINE 
            %The chapter number only if it's greater than 0
            }
\fancyhead[LO]{\runheadsize\runheadstyle\itshape\rightmark}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\ifnum\value{chapter}=0 \runheadsize\runheadstyle\itshape\thepage \fi%
                \ifnum\value{chapter}>0 \runheadsize\runheadstyle\thepage \fi}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}%
  \fancyhf{}%
  \fancyfoot[RE,LO]{\runheadsize\runheadstyle\thepage}%
}
\begin{document}

\mainmatter
\chapter{Introduction to General Chemistry Laboratory} \label{chapter:1.ICL}
\markboth{Introduction to Chemistry Laboratory}{}

This lab is designed to introduce you to the general chemistry lab: the physical facilities, the equipment we will be using, and basic skills in data collection and analysis that we will expect you to know.

\section{Background: Equipment and Glassware} \label{section:1.Background}

Throughout the semester, we will be using different pieces of equipment and glassware; it is important that you know the name of what you will be using, as well as when it is appropriate to use it. A discussion of some of the most common types of glassware and equipment is included here. Pictures of these, and other pieces of equipment, are available on p. \tit{\pageref{section:Glass}} of this lab manual. Other glassware and equipment will be presented to you during the course of the semester as needed.

\subsection{Lab Glassware} \label{subsection:LG}

Lab glassware is typically made of \tit{borosilicate} glass (name brands you may be familiar with include Pyrex and Kimax). This special kind of glass is more resistant to chemicals and heat than regular glass, which means we can use it without worrying too much about it being etched with chemicals, or shattering when the temperature changes suddenly, like regular glass might.
\end{document}
```

Comment: This looks like the `cmss` font. I don't know of any "slanted" vertical bar in CM, but you might try an ordinary roman slash.  It might just have a slope close to the slope of `cmss`.

Comment: @barbarabeeton It is apparently just a \slshape\textbar but it does not produce the slant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You write,

> I do not want to change the encoding of my file, i.e. utf8 to T1.

Actually, there is no conflict: `utf8` specifies an *input* encoding while `T1` specifies an output or, more precisely, *font* encoding.

The default font encoding for the `svmono` document class appears to be `OT1`. As you've (re-)discovered, `|` doesn't "work" as expected in text mode. (Same goes for the `>` and `<` symbols, by the way!) In addition, `\textbar` produces a vertical rather than a slanted "|" symbol.

However, if you add the instruction

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
```

to the preamble, `|` works exactly as expected. Of course, you are free to replace `|` with `\textbar`: with the `T1` font encoding in effect, its output will be a *slanted* bar as well.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to want `\textup{/}`.

```latex
\RequirePackage{fix-cm}
\documentclass[envcountchap,sectrefs,12pt]{svmono} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage[
  paperwidth=8.5in,
  paperheight=11in,includeall,
  twoside,
  inner=1in,
  outer=0.5in,
  top=1cm,
  bottom=0.7cm,
  marginparwidth=1.75in,
  headsep=0.25in,
  heightrounded
]{geometry}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[RE]{%
  \runheadsize\runheadstyle\slshape
  %The chapter number only if > 0
  \ifnum\value{chapter}>0
    Experiment \thechapter\ \textup{/}\ 
  \fi
  \leftmark
}
\fancyhead[LO]{\runheadsize\runheadstyle\slshape\rightmark}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{%
  \runheadsize\runheadstyle
  \ifnum\value{chapter}=0 \itshape\fi
  \thepage
}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}%
  \fancyhf{}%
  \fancyfoot[RE,LO]{\runheadsize\runheadstyle\thepage}%
}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesection\ #1}}

\newcommand{\tit}{\textit}

\begin{document}

\mainmatter
\chapter{Introduction to General Chemistry Laboratory} \label{chapter:1.ICL}
%\markboth{Introduction to Chemistry Laboratory}{}

This lab is designed to introduce you to the general chemistry lab: the physical 
facilities, the equipment we will be using, and basic skills in data collection 
and analysis that we will expect you to know.

\section{Background: Equipment and Glassware} \label{section:1.Background}

Throughout the semester, we will be using different pieces of equipment and glassware; 
it is important that you know the name of what you will be using, as well as when it 
is appropriate to use it. A discussion of some of the most common types of glassware 
and equipment is included here. Pictures of these, and other pieces of equipment, are 
available on p. \tit{\pageref{section:Glass}} of this lab manual. Other glassware and 
equipment will be presented to you during the course of the semester as needed.

\subsection{Lab Glassware} \label{subsection:LG}

Lab glassware is typically made of \tit{borosilicate} glass (name brands you may be 
familiar with include Pyrex and Kimax). This special kind of glass is more resistant 
to chemicals and heat than regular glass, which means we can use it without worrying 
too much about it being etched with chemicals, or shattering when the temperature 
changes suddenly, like regular glass might.

\lipsum[1-20]

\end{document}
```

I did some changes to optimize the code. Also I changed `\itshape` for the sections in the header, to match the `\slshape` for chapter.

[image]

Comment: But the slope of the vertical bar in the header isn't the same as that of the slanted font.  Compare the 1 and I on either side.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Should it be?

Comment: Yes.  Look carefully at the second attachment in the question.